# Perl - search in a string

Tags: perl

I would like to know, if `$search` is not in the `$content`. The search string should not be in the h2 tag.

```
my $search="Hello World";
my $content="<p>Hello World<h2>Is Hello World inside this tag?</h2><p>Thank you";

if ($content !~ /<h2>.*?($search \<\/h2\>)/;) {}
```

This works not. Has anybody an idea?

Comment: `!=~` should be `!~`.

Comment: Remove the semicolon at the end of the if condition.

Comment: @choroba: That will send it hunting for `<h2>` until it finds *any* `</h2>` within an intervening `$search`

Comment: `if ( $content =~ m|<h2>(.*?)</h2>| and $1 !~ m|$search| ) { ... }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`</h2>` doesn't immediately follow `$search`. But adding `.*` or `.*?` after `$search` in the regex still doesn't fix it fully, e.g. it thinks the following is "inside":

```
my $content="<h2>Is it inside this tag?</h2><p>Thank you Hello World</h2>";
```

This might be what you want:

```
my $inside;
while ($content =~ m{(<h2>.*?</h2>)}g) {
    my $h2 = $1;
    $inside = 1 if -1 != index $h2, $search;
}
say $inside ? 'yes' : 'no';
```

But it would be even better to parse the content by an HTML parser.

Answer (score 0):

I'd strongly suggest using a proper HTML parser; here I'm using [`Mojo::DOM`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::DOM) because it has a fairly modern interface, but there are several other modules available.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Mojo::DOM;

my $search="Hello World";
my $content="<p>Hello World<h2>Is Hello World inside this tag?</h2><p>Thank you";

my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new($content);
my $found = defined($dom->find('h2')->map('all_text')->first(qr/\Q$search\E/));

print $found ? "Found it\n" : "Didn't find it\n";

__END__

Found it
```